# Put a variable in plinq statement

Tags: .net, linq, plinq

I'm new with LINQ and I try to make a statement like this where I have a variable called status and takes a different value but how can I do this because I have this error

Error   CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'

```
    IEnumerable<Student> queryResult3 = new DataContext().Students.Where(s => s.BirthDate.Year < 1955).ToList().ForEach(s =>
    { string status = s.Year_Result < 12 ? "KO" : "OK";}) ;
```

Comment: I found a solution :)             var result = new DataContext().Students.Where(s => s.BirthDate.Year < 1955).Select(
                st => new { st.Last_Name, st.Year_Result, Status = st.Year_Result < 12 ? "KO" : "OK" });

Comment: { string status = s.Year_Result < 12 ? "KO" : "OK";} doesnt return anything. Its basically the same as if you had a void ReturnNothing(){ }. Your left side required it to return a IEnumerable<Student>. Your answer creates a new list of anonymous object which is fine, since you changed the left side to var result. If you wanted a list of students, inside  this, you could change Select( st => new Student(st.Last_Name, st.Year_Result, Status = st.Year_Result < 12 ? "KO" : "OK" ) or whatever your constructor for student looks like